# Semi-transparent application bar

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm a WP7 newbie.  I would like to make it semi-transparent so the whole page can see. However, I serach the internet and didn't find how to do it. Would someone provide an example or link for me. Thanks in advance.

There is my code:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="true" IsMenuEnabled="True" BackgroundColor="FloralWhite" ForegroundColor="LightGreen">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="images/light/flag.png" Text="Call Response"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="images/buttons/call.png" Text="Call"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="images/buttons/createEvent.png" Text="New Event"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="images/buttons/eventCompleted.png" Text="Completed"/>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you just set Opacity...

```
Opacity="0.5"
```

Which results in this....

[image]

Code in full...

```
<Rectangle Height="210" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="66,474,0,0" Name="rectangle1" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="Chartreuse" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="134" />
```

...

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True" Opacity=".75" BackgroundColor="Aqua" ForegroundColor="AliceBlue">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button1.png" Text="Button 1"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button2.png" Text="Button 2"/>
```